# How to load XML locale file natively

Tags: c++

I'm building a game with SFML and I'm looking for a way to localize it. I've seen many topics saying that XML is a good file type to write localization for programs. However in most examples they simply say how to write the XML file or how to load it with GUI managers such as Qt, but I'm not using any of those. What I need is the actual way to load those language files based on the system language, preferably a cross-platform way. Statically compiling and loading one language would kind of defeat the purpose of localization.

Comment: For the record, SFML has nothing to do with localisation nor XML.

Comment: @Hiura I know, I'm just exposing the library I use for my project so they don't just come and say "use Qt's translator thing". There must be a cross-platform native way to get the system language on runtime, but I had no luck because all the search lead me to threads about which file type to use. I'm sure finding and using an XML parser is easy, but the rest not quite.

Comment: The fact that `SFML` is in both the title and tagged to the question is misleading and will attract less people.

Comment: Well I think I found a dodgy way to do it. `setlocale` returns the locale string, so I'll just use the first two letters to find which language (who cares about the region, I'm writing neutral text), then do an ugly if-else to identify the right file to load...

Comment: I would rather use an OS-specific function to detect the language used by the user. The locale might be unset or even wrong I believe.

Comment: How can the locale not be set, unless it's an extremely old OS? Pretty much every OS I've seen up to now set it for the language and the date format... What would be those functions? Now that I think about it, it might just be better that I do `setlocale` for stuff like accents in French and simply load a config file with the default language as English. What I ask is maybe too complicated for nothing, but at least I have the XML parser going, I just need to make my detector better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I decided to use a configuration file instead. I implemented a xml parser sucessfully for both the config file and the language files. I kept the `setlocale` function only if the user specifies that he wants his system language, might be set to that by default and if the locale fails, the user can change the config to any language.